# Maven 3.6.2 issue during dependency download

Tags: maven, maven-3

I'm getting below . Can someone please let me know why is this happening?

> [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one
>   of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5:
>   Could not transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Please add some explanation so other can understand !
And if possible add your tried code so we can help you.

Comment: Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\wtr\OneDrive - FRG\Documents\VDIW10MCS142\ban_testautomation\Framework\pom.xml clean install exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=mainTest.MainExecutor -Dexec.args=bwp_uat FOREX
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for LitmusFramework:LitmusFramework:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for axis:axis:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}\libr\lib_service\axis.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the exception:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

You do no have inserted the certificate of the maven repository into the truststore of your jvm.

So download the certificate, insert it using keytool to the cacerts file of your jvm `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/` and try again.

It maybe the url of maven repo is nt the reaseon.So try maven option -X to see which URL caused the problem